# How to calculate working time on this table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database with following structure

```
ID        EmployeeID        DateTime
1          250              29/11/2015 6:00:00 AM
2          251              29/11/2015 6:01:25 AM
3          252              29/11/2015 7:30:05 AM
4          250              29/11/2015 1:30:45 PM
5          252              29/11/2015 1:32:20 PM
6          251              29/11/2015 4:36:41 PM
7          250              30/11/2015 8:30:50 AM
8          250              30/11/2015 3:45:22 PM
```

this table store times that each employee enters or exits. now I want to make a query to have this data:

first employee id, and the next two columns are enter and exit time

```
EmployeeID        DateTime                  DateTime2
250               29/11/2015 6:00:00 AM     29/11/2015 1:30:45 PM
251               29/11/2015 6:01:25 AM     29/11/2015 4:36:41 PM
252               29/11/2015 7:30:05 AM     29/11/2015 1:32:20 PM
250               30/11/2015 8:30:50 AM     30/11/2015 3:45:22 PM
```

please help me to make this query

Comment: Hey, 4 people dedicated their time to solve your problem. It would be nice of you if you showed us the curtesy of accepting an answer or at least comment on why those are not the answers you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the greatest piece of sql but this will definitely give you what your after

```
SELECT e1.EmployeeID, e1.[DateTime] As StartDateTime, e2.[DateTime] As EndDateTime
  FROM [EmployeeAccess] e1
    INNER JOIN [EmployeeAccess] e2 ON 
                     e1.Employeeid = e2.employeeid 
                     and e1.datetime <> e2.datetime 
                     and e1.DateTime < e2.datetime
                     and cast(e1.datetime as date) = cast(e2.datetime as date)
```

The join the same table together with the following rules:

1. Match by EmployeeID
2. ensure the datetimes are not the same exactly (removes joins of same entry)
3. ensure the datetime in e1 is less than datetime in e2 (removes joins where e2 is greater than e1)
4. ensure that only match same days entries (ensure only join same day matches)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one entry and exit time per day per employee, you can just group by the date which will sort correctly as well:

```
Select 
    EmployeeID, 
    Min([DateTime]) As DateTime1, 
    Max([DateTime]) As DateTime2
From 
    YourLogTable
Group By 
    Fix([DateTime]),
    EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one entry/exit per day or a shift could go into the next day (overnight), you could use the following:

```
SELECT 
  T1.EmployeeID, 
  T1.DateTime as EntryTime, 
  Min(T2.DateTime) as ExitTime
FROM TheTable as T1 
  INNER JOIN TheTable as T2 
  ON (T1.EmployeeID = T2.EmployeeID AND T1.DateTime < T2.DateTime)
GROUP BY T1.DateTime, T1.EmployeeID
HAVING (count(T2.DateTime) mod2)=1;
```

This works as long as you have an Exit for every Entry for every employee. 
If you can't guarantee that it gets a bit nastier but still is possible:

```
SELECT 
  T1.EmployeeID, 
  T1.DateTime as EntryTime, 
  Min(T2.DateTime) as ExitTime
FROM (TheTable as T1 
  INNER JOIN TheTable as T2 
  ON (T1.EmployeeID = T2.EmployeeID AND T1.DateTime < T2.DateTime))
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(DateTime) as EmployeeRecordCount FROM TheTable GROUP BY EmployeeID
     ) AS T3 ON T1.EmployeeID = T3.EmployeeID
GROUP BY T1.DateTime, T1.EmployeeID
HAVING ((count(T2.DateTime) mod 2)<>(FIRST(T3.EmployeeRecordCount) mod 2));
```

What this does is (for every Employee):

- Join every record with the one that has the lowest time greater than its own:
  `Min(T2.DateTime) as ExitTime` for `T1.DateTime < T2.DateTime`
- then join to that the total count of Entries for this Employee:
  `INNER JOIN (SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(DateTime) as EmployeeRecordCount FROM TheTable GROUP BY EmployeeID) AS T3`.
- Now if the EmployeeRecordCount is even, select only the Rows where the joined table `T2` has an uneven count of DateTimes and vice versa.

(Of ocurse `HAVING ((count(T1.DateTime) mod 2)=(FIRST(T3.EmployeeRecordCount) mod 2))`would give the same results.)